# Food preservation in refrigerator

Tags: freezing, food-preservation

I am an international student in France and as I live alone, products are put in fridge for later use after being opened. Two months in and I never had a problem with storing food in it but today I opened my plastic-sealed prosciutto only to realise that mold had build up in it. I checked the expiration date and it had another 2 months until it went rotten.

After further inspection, it turned out that the chicken nuggets, this time opened, had been severely infected by mold too. Needless to say that I threw away every meat in my fridge afterwards.

I wanted to ask whether a possible cause might have been an inadequate, high temperature? The gradient was set on 2nd level but it was enough for ice to freeze on the inside. Moreover, what's a rule of thumb for the maximum time of fridge-storage for some categories of food?